# Unsplash API - fetching background image by keyword in React Weather App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been self-teaching myself React and wanted to work on making a weather app. It is a bit unconventional as instead of fetching actual weather information from an api, I just wanted to mess  around a bit and set temperature randomly using Math.random (it is just a practice project, not anything to be taken seriously).

Essentially, I have a 'weatherType' variable that prescribes a keyword to a certain temperature, e.g. at 21 degrees celsius weatherType = 'Sunny'. Then with Unsplash API, I am fetching an image that matches this keyword, so a picture of a beach, for instance, and this background image is stored in my 'container' class.

I have spent quite a lot of time messing around with this (much more than I planned to!). The fetch is happening, but the background image and weatherType keeps reloading and flipping from image to image until quickly going over the fetch limit. It should just be fetching one background image UNTIL the page is manually reloaded again.

I felt that this had something to do with the useEffect dependency array, and at the moment the only way that the app is working as intended is with leaving the dependency array empty, however this is unpractical as I keep getting a warning (React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchBackgroundImg'.), and disabling the warning does not help.

Everything to do with the API call is happening in my App component.
Here is my App.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react'; 
import { useEffect} from "react"; 
import axios from 'axios';

import Forecast from "./components/Forecast";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import WeeklyForecast from "./components/WeeklyForecast";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

import './App.css';

// Generate a temperature from -5 to 40 degrees
const currentTempGenerated = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 46) - 5;

function App() {

  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState('London'); 

  function updateLocation(newLocation) {
    setCurrentLocation(newLocation);
  }

  // State variable to store the current temperature
  const [currentTemp, setCurrentTemp] = useState(0);


  // Calculate weather type based on current temperature
  const getWeatherType = (temp) => {
    if (temp >= -5 && temp <= -1) {
      return 'Snow';
    } else if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 3) {
      return 'Fog';
    } else if (temp >= 4 && temp <= 10) {
      return 'Rain';
    } else if (temp >= 11 && temp <= 13) {
      return 'Drizzle';
    } else if (temp >= 14 && temp <= 16) {
    return 'Clouds';
  } else if (temp >= 17 && temp <= 20) {
    return 'Cloudy';
  } else if (temp >= 21 && temp <= 28) {
    return 'Sunny';
  } else if (temp >= 29 && temp <= 31) {
    return 'Thunder';
  } else if (temp >= 32 && temp <= 40) {
    return 'Heat';
  } else {
    return 'n/a';
  }
};

// State variable to store fetched image URL
const [backgroundImg, setBackgroundImg] = useState(null); // initialised with null

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY;

// Default image
  const defaultBackgroundImg =
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464822759023-fed622ff2c3b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80';

// Fetch image from Unsplash
const fetchBackgroundImg = async (weatherType) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?query=${weatherType}&client_id=${apiKey}`
    );

    const imageURL = response.data.urls.regular;
    setBackgroundImg(imageURL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching image from Unsplash.com:', error);
    setBackgroundImg(defaultBackgroundImg);
  }
};


useEffect(() => {
  const temp = currentTempGenerated();
  setCurrentTemp(temp);
  const weatherType = getWeatherType(temp);
  fetchBackgroundImg(weatherType);
}, []);


  return (
  <div className='container'style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImg || defaultBackgroundImg})`, backgroundSize: "cover", backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'}}>

    <h1 className='logo'>Weatherly</h1>

    <span className='search-forecast'>
      <SearchBar updateLocation={updateLocation} 
      />
      <Forecast currentTemp={currentTemp} location={currentLocation} 
      />
    </span>

    <WeeklyForecast currentTemp={currentTemp}/>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If anyone has a way of fixing my code that would be very much appreciated!
Thanks very much!